# Access to IR-Blaster of Revue?

Tags: google-tv, logitech

Does someone know if it is possible to access the IR-Blaster of the Revue programatically?
I need to change the Input-Source of the TV, but i cannot find any information about that.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API on Google TV to do that. Use Anymote to change the TV input source.